# Issues with Uploading Flv files in PHP

Tags: php

i have uploaded flv files to site , but it does get corrupted files, im using this code to upload the files.

```
$sample_obj->mimes = array('flv'=> array('video/x-flv', 'text/plain'),
                           'swf'=> array('video/swf',   'application/octet-stream'));
```

What mime-type is correct for flv files?

Comment: What kind of corrupted files? What do they contain?

Answer (score 0):

```
video/x-flv
flv-application/octet-stream
```

Answer (score 0):

change `Max_File_size`(default 2mb) to some more in `php_ini` file on server or wam.

Comment: Are the files getting truncated or are they the wrong encoding?